# Batch cmd closes with ascii art?

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe, ascii

I'm trying to make a ascii skull in batch, yet the cmd doesn't show my art OR text when opened

```
start cmd.exe
@echo off
color a
cls

echo                 ^_________-----_____^
echo       ^____------           __      ----_^
echo^___----             ___------              \^
echo   ^----________        ----                 \^
echo        ^       -----__    |             _____)^
echo                    ^__-                /     \^
echo        ^_______-----    ___--          \    /)\^
echo  ^------_______      ---____            \__/  /^
echo               ^-----__    \ --    _          /\^
echo                      ^--__--__     \_____/   \_/\^
echo                              ^----|   /          |^
echo                                  ^|  |___________|^
echo                                  ^|  | ((_(_)| )_)^
echo                                  ^|  \_((_(_)|/(_)^
echo                                  ^\             (^
echo                                   ^\_____________)^

echo !OVER-PRICED COMPUTER ALERT!
echo !TERMINATE!
```

yet again, when I open my file NOTHING shows up. any help?

Comment: Why do you `start cmd.exe`? It just opens an additional console window. Do you perhaps want this message to appear as a welcome message when opening an interactive console session?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You hadn't [escaped command character](http://ss64.com/nt/echo.html) i.e. **" | "** with **" ^ "** in your script.

Here is the corrected & modified version of your script

```
@echo off
color a
cls

echo                  _________-----_____
echo        ____------           __      ----_
echo  ___----             ___------              \
echo     ----________        ----                 \
echo                -----__    ^|             _____)
echo                     __-                /     \
echo         _______-----    ___--          \    /)\
echo   ------_______      ---____            \__/  /
echo                -----__    \ --    _          /\
echo                       --__--__     \_____/   \_/\
echo                               ---^|   /          ^|
echo                                  ^| ^|___________^|
echo                                  ^| ^| ((_(_)^| )_)
echo                                  ^|  \_((_(_)^|/(_)
echo                                   \             (
echo                                    \_____________)

echo !OVER-PRICED COMPUTER ALERT!
echo !TERMINATE!
pause>nul
```

Removed `start cmd.exe` as pointed out by [@DanielB](https://superuser.com/questions/1104488/batch-cmd-closes-with-ascii-art/#comment-1570441) and made it to pause with no comment by adding `pause>nul`

[image]

Comment: The carets are not needed before the underscores.

Comment: @dbenham Yeah, ones not followed by | or any other command character can be skipped. Edited

Comment: - Lovely art. I use ascii art in log files (to separate sections), and different ascii pictures to identify and differentiate release versions. But point is, I have always found it easier to put the art in a txt file, and use a command like `type` or  equivalent. Ascii art for the win